# Number of lower-ed words in a text. Python

Tags: python, string

To lower the words of a text, we use the command

```
text.lower()
```

Is there a built-in function that tells me the number of words that text.lower() has changed?

Comment: No there is not. Why do you want this and in what sort of context?

Comment: `sum(1 for x,y in zip(text,text.lower()) if x != y)`

Comment: Thanks! I am just practising my skills in python.

Comment: @XinHuang that doesn't count words, just letters which are different.

Answer (score 2):

no built-in but easy using `sum` and a generator comprehension:

```
text = "I am the World"

print(sum(1 for x in text.split() if x.lower()!=x))
```

prints: 2

`str.split` splits the words according to spaces, and we iterate on the words, comparing each word against its lowercase flavour, issuing 1 to `sum` if there's a difference.